# startNewActivity many times lifecycle miss understanding

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, android-intent

in oncreate of activity A

```
while(i<5){
startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
Log.v(tag,"activity A");
}
```

in activity B inside oncreate

```
Log.v(tag,"activity B");
finish();
```

and then in the console I see something like this

```
activity A
activity A
activity A
activity A
activity A
activity B
activity B
activity B
activity B
activity B
```

What should I change to have situation where the output is like this

```
activity A
activity B
activity A
activity B
activity A
activity B
```

I mean for every startActivity method I want new activity to actually to be started. Cause the activity B actually lives for a fraction of moment it is started and than finished. My problem is in the understanding the activity lifecycle. I expected that when I call srartActivity the activity to be started indeed, but it doesn't happens.

Edit1:
ok I pasted just a small snippet of my code. and the problem is not in the while loop, in my real project is wrote correctly with initialization of the i variable like int i-0; and incrementing inside the loop like i++; . . . As you can see the output from the app is good, everything is get called in a sertian number of times and so on, but the problem is the order of calling. it is like startActivity doesn't start the activity after the call of the srartActivity, instead every thing is started after oncreate of activityA is finished.

Comment: You have used while(i<5) loop.Are you sure it is not the problem...

Comment: He might have missed these lines "int i=0;" and "i++;". But that is not his problem.

Comment: @VineetShukla y would i<5 be a problem??

Comment: very strange behavior.gud question

Comment: not at all strange behaviour. it takes time before a new Activity is started. and the startActivity method is a non-blocking one and that is why he gets this output

Comment: @Dennis: he is putting the startactivity in a loop and whole code is not shared.So, if the while loop will keep it's execution then? and the print statements are 5 in no...

Comment: @VineetShukla actually that is quiet understandable that he missed that while writing.u can see console output also

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu thks 4 the explnation.

Comment: I have make an edit1 to stop the confusion about the while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not just about activity lifecycle, but also about the message processing in the main thread (=UI thread) of your app.
startActivity returns immediately after sending the intent, so the while loop fires 5 intents to start Activity B within a very short time before returning control to the thread's message loop.
Only after returning from the current method call, your applications main thread can start processing the previously generated messages that will result in creating the 5 instances of Acitvity 5, once again one after the other.

If you want Activity A to hold off until Activity B has finished, you can call [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) - once!. Then, in Activity B, call finish( int) to return a result to Activity A. Override [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) in Activity A to get the result code and from here you can again start Acitity B if needed.

See also [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)